# Check if button has been clicked more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of 3 tabs and everytime i click on the same tab it replays the fade-in animation and blinks and i need it to only show the animation when i click on a new tab and not display the fade-in animation when i click on the same tab.

Its because it removes and re-adds the same class everytime i click at it.

what i currently have is:

```
(function ($) {
    var tabs = $(".tabs li a");
    
    tabs.on("click", function () {
      var content = this.hash.replace("/", "");
      tabs.removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
      $("#content").find("section").hide();
      $(content).fadeIn(200);
    });
  })

<ul class="tabs">
          <li><a class="active" href="#/one">Tab 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#/two">Tab 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#/three">Tab 3</a></li>
        </ul>
```

What i have tried:

```
// if tab is clicked/selected then remove animation
if(!$(tabs).data("clicked")) {
        $(content).fadeIn(200);
      } else {
          $(content).fadeIn(0);
      }
      $(".active").data('clicked', true);
```

```
// if click count is higher than 1 then remove animation
var trigger = $(this),
        clickCount = trigger.data('clickCount');

        clickCount++;

        trigger.data('clickCount', clickCount);

        if(clickCount > 1) {
            $(content).fadeIn(0);
        }
```

Comment: Why not just check if it is visible and not run the animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried like that :

```
var tabs = $(".tabs li a");

tabs.on("click", function () {

  if( !$(this).hasClass("active") ){
    var content = this.hash.replace("/", "");
    $("#content").find("section").hide();
    $(content).fadeIn(200);
    $(".tabs li").find(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  }


});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest always check if `active` class exists before adding it.
And only if it doesn't exist add this class and animation.
In this case if `active` class exists you will not be able to add this class again and the animation not be triggered again.

Answer (score 0):

in JavaScript

element is the button you need specifically.
you can get the button id using a simple Js query

```js
var element = document.getElementById('buttonID');
```

```js
element.on('click', (){
  let counter = 0;
    return function inner() {
        counter++;
        console.log('Number of clicks: ' + counter);
    };
})
```